# lombok constant need to mvn install

Tags: java, lombok, spring-tool-suite

I have a java spring boot project that uses Lombok. I love this library as it reduces code.

I have a problem here. That every time I switch on my spring-tool-suite project, I need to do:

`mvn clean`
`mvn install`
`mvn update`

to resolve `get` `set` dependency compilation errors.

Comment: What do you mean by 'switch on my spring-tool-suite project'? It looks like one of your projects depends on another or one of them is missing a proper configuration in IDE. The "Spring tools" aren't any kind of build tool (check what the "build tool" is pls) so it's unaware of your other changes. Finally, I guess the configuration is missing, take a look of having/making multi-module projects in maven so you could easily work on both.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your IDE with lombok.
1.execute lombok.jar and configure IDE
2.Restart IDE
   a)if IDE not working after configuration
   1)goto IDE installation HOME folder and open **STS.ini** file add
 
**-vmargs**

**-javaagent:lombok.jar** 
this two line code ther.
**Note**:-keep your lombok.jar in IDE installation folder also